# How to make data validation in excel from a range which is discontinuous

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have some data in range "A1:A10". I want to create a data validation list in range "B1".

I have created a group which has data from "A1:A5" and "A8:A10". Lets say the group name is "mango". Now I want to create the data validation in the cell "B1" from this group(mango). When I try to create it

It throws an error "The source currently evaluates to an error". Can some one help me to accomplish this

Comment: You cannot set non-continuous Range of cells as Validation Source List. That's why it throws error. As what Gary mentioned below, use helper cells! :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you to avoid including cells **A6** and **A7** in the DV list.  To accomplish this try:

```
Sub DisJointDatJoint()
    Dim rDV As Range, sDV As String
    Set rDV = Range("A1:A5,A8:A10")
    sDV = ""
    For Each r In rDV
        sDV = sDV & r.Value & ","
    Next r
    sDV = Mid(sDV, 1, Len(sDV) - 1)
    With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=sDV
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Just be aware that the static list approach lacks volatility..........an alternative approach would be to use "helper" cells.